# PuTTY closes after login

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, unix, putty

I'm logging in through my schools host and everything works fine, I exited earlier and now anytime I try to log back in, PuTTY automatically closes. I also used the Google Shell to see if it was an issue with PuTTY but I still get logged out. Here is the output I get:

```
Last login: Tue Feb 14 21:51:02 2017 from rsrch-bd09s72.ucads.uc.edu
/home/ep69674/.profile[3]: Class: not found [No such file or directory]
/home/ep69674/.profile[7]: 1.: not found [No such file or directory]
/home/ep69674/.profile[14]: 2.: not found [No such file or directory]
/home/ep69674/.profile[15]: what: not found [No such file or directory]
/home/ep69674/.profile[22]: 3.: not found [No such file or directory]
/home/ep69674/.profile[29]: 4.: not found [No such file or directory]
/home/ep69674/.profile[32]: ________________: not found [No such file or directory]
/home/ep69674/.profile[36]: 5.: not found [No such file or directory]
/home/ep69674/.profile: line 36: syntax error: `(' unexpected
Connection to rwclinux.rwc.uc.edu closed.
NaCl plugin exited with status code 3.
```

**Side note: I'm also using SSH**

Answer (score 3):

It seems as though your `.profile` file has become corrupted, and is preventing your account from logging in.

This will likely require you to contact your system administrator to fix the file.

I've looked through a few "How to bypass .profile on login" articles, and though I don't have access to PuTTY to see if these flags can be set somehow, specifying `bash --noprofile` as the remote command might allow you to login.

Someone also reported that they were able to regain control by sending <kbd>Control-C</kbd> during the login process.

Should you be able to get access to your account this way, you may wish to 
run

```
mv .profile .profile-copy
```

so you can get back into your account without trickery in the future.

Comment: To specify the remote command, go to *Connection > SSH > Remote Command*.

Answer (score 2):

Try to copy the `.profile` from the remote using `pscp.exe`, for backup:

```
pscp user@host:.profile .profile.bak
```

And then replace it with an empty file:

```
echo > empty
pscp empty user@host:.profile
```

As a sanity check, try to login again using PuTTY. With the new empty `.profile`, it should work. Then edit the copy of `.profile` locally, try to fix the errors, and copy it back to the server. Repeat until all problems in `.profile` are resolved (you successfully log in).